# Colour a cell based on the length of time between that date cell and another date cell

Tags: google-sheets

**This query is in relation to Google Sheets.**

If the date in B1 is 10 days older than the date in A1, then B1 is shaded red.

If the date in B1 is within 10 days of the date in A1, then B1 is shaded green.

Does anyone know how I can do this please?

**We hope to use this as follows:**

1. Record the date we submit a product.
2. Record a date to show we have detailed the product as suitable.
   (We want this to be within 10 days of us initially submitting the product.)

Therefore we submit a product on the date in A1

We then detail the product as suitable and record this date in B1.

If we have done this within 10 days, B1 should be green. If not, it should be red. This will help us deal with delays.

Does anyone know how I can do this within Google Sheets please?

Comment: Format / Conditional Formatting; create a rule Format Cells if "Date is after"; select Exact Date and put in the appropriate formula; set the required Formatting style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *Format > Conditional Formatting* for the column B, defining the range from the *second* row:

```
B2:B1000
```

You have to set the range this way because the formula is always evaluating in its top left corner first. So you can get the past date from row 1 and formatting the cell in row 2.

You should format your cells with *custom formula* like:

```
=DATEDIF(A1,A2,"D")>10
```

Your B column by default can be green.

You can check my demo sheet for this problem [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yb_BAGMCd1A64p3LSu6ddkViL1zsJRbOi1UXEvEI-UA/edit?usp=sharing).

---

```
DATEDIF:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055612?hl=en
Conditional Formatting:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413
```